# Android camera intent in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, camera, navigation-drawer

i have a problem with my first app!
My app is an navigation drawer. It has 2 fragmets where i show diferentes this.
- user fragment where i show user's info
- action screen where the user can use the camera and take a photo.

In user fragment i dont have any problem, but in camera fragment i have many problems!

I did a fragment where i have a button and an imageview (camera_image.xml)

And, CameraImage.java in the java directory.

Then, a put the code:

CameraImagen.java:

```
public class CameraImage extends Fragment {

private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1888;
Button button2;
ImageView imageView2;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_image,
            container, false);

    button2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent,
                    CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });

    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            // convert byte array to Bitmap

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
                    byteArray.length);

            imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
    }
}
}
```

camera_image.xlm

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.diegoperez.myfirstapp.CameraImage">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

in Manifest.xlm, i add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In the navigation drawer java class, i add:

```
CameraImage fragment = new CameraImage();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

In the camera_image.java i have this problem:

[image: Error]

Then i tried to modify this .java and i wrote this:

```
public class CameraImage extends Fragment {

private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1888;
Button button2;
ImageView imageView2;


public CameraImage() {
    // Constructor vacío
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_image, container, false);

    return rootView;
}



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            // convert byte array to Bitmap

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
                    byteArray.length);

            imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
    }
}

public void tomar_foto (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
}
```

the app runs, i can open the fragment with the button but when i push it, the app crash and close itseft.

I need help please...two days with this problems!
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported :

`import android.view.View;`

or

`import android.view.View.OnclickListener` ?

Also try to change the `onClickListener()` for this one :

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent,
                CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

}
});
```

Comment: I did the modification but it does not work. If i put int like




button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent,
                CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

}
});






the app close when i go to the fragment. But if i put like:

public void take_photo (){
...
}

it closes when i push th button.

Comment: Here is: 
`11-11 15:50:29.023 25849-25849/com.example.diegoperez.myfirstapp W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d7c2a0)
11-11 15:50:29.046 25849-25849/com.example.diegoperez.myfirstapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 15:50:29.046 25849-25849/com.example.diegoperez.myfirstapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 15:50:29.046 25849-25849/com.example.diegoperez.myfirstapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.diegoperez.myfirstapp.CameraImage.onCreateView(CameraImage.java:31)`

Comment: Solved it @DiegoPerez ? or shall I modify the answer

Comment: Try to put it on onViewCreated